# Debugging support for nestjs mono repo

Tags: visual-studio-code, nestjs

I have a project using nestjs mono repo. I am trying to start multiple service in debug mode.

I tried `nest --debug` option but that only start a single service for other services it throws error for debug port already in used.

Is there anyway to start multiple microservices in debug mode in Visual Studio Code.

Thanks